# Office addon on MacOS getFileAsync. Internal error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-js

I am following the docs page from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word?view=office-js

I am trying to get the currently opened document in Office JS addon to send it to another server using a POST request.

I added the code snippet from the docs, same as the docs. the only difference I have is that I am using react, but that should not affect the office-js API

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
        Office.FileType.Compressed,
        { sliceSize: 100000 },
        result => {
            console.log(result);
```

But. The result is 'failed' and there is an error as you can see here

```
code: 5001

message: "An internal error has occurred."

name: "Internal Error"

status: "failed"
```

I tried to sideload the addon in office online, then the function worked correctly. It is only not working in MacOS version of office uptill now

Answer (score -1):

For many Macs, the maximum slice size is 65536. That usually causes the 'failed' status. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback- under 'Remarks'.